# Is it possible to get a notification in metasploit?

Tags: metasploit, kali-linux

Is it possible to get a notification after a victim download a infected file. So that i must not spend days to wait for a conection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting a notification means that you have to **setup a listener** so it can receive this notification whenever someone installs this payload.

So it's the same, you can simply setup your listener to work in the background of your system, and **automate some scripts** to do regular 'hacking stuff'.

If it's a must, then instead of automate a script, use some programming skills to replace that automation with sound playing script, and that will be your notification.

Comment: @Emmadeddin Can i do it with python?

Comment: Maybe, I'm not familiar with Python or Perl. That's will be another question.